# нужен скрипт для интернет магазина! у меня все товары дублируется

Tags: php, javascript, css, phpmyadmin

Необходимо сделать скрипт, который сможет автоматически задавать нужные классы элементам.
Для четных элементов - `fl`, а для нечетных - `fr`
Сейчас все товары дублируются

Вот код:

```
figure class="<strong>fl</strong> main-column-figure"
figure class="<strong>fr</strong> main-column-figure"

<div class="select_items">
        <div class="main-columns-wrapper">
            <?php
                        echo'
                                <figure class="fl main-column-figure">
                                    <div class="product-corner top"></div>
                                            <a href="">
                                              <img class="radius5-top" src="'.$img_path.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" alt="'.$row["title"].'">
                                            </a>
                                    <figcaption class="radius5-bott">
                                        <div class=" fl">
                                            <h3 class="cont-col-header"><a href="">'.$row["title"].'</a></h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="price2 fr "><a href=""><span class="price-font2">'.$row["price"].'</span> тг.</a></p>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </figure>
                              <figure class="fr main-column-figure">
                                    <div class="product-corner top"></div>
                                          <a href="">
                                          <img class="radius5-top" src="'.$img_path.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" alt="'.$row["title"].'">
                                        </a>
                                    <figcaption class="radius5-bott">
                                        <div class=" fl">
                                            <h3 class="cont-col-header"><a href="">'.$row["title"].'</a></h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="price2 fr "><a href=""><span class="price-font2">'.$row["price"].'</span> тг.</a></p>
                                    </figcaption>
                              </figure>
                        ';
                    }
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
                }
                
            ?>
        </div>
```

Сейчас выглядит так
[image: Должно выглядеть так]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [нужен скрипт для интернет магазина! у меня все товары дублируется Надо чтобы для нечетных тизеров надо добавить класс fl, а для нечетных - fr](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/648583/%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%be-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be

Answer (score 0):

Если эти классы используются только для задания стилей через CSS, то можно обойтись только CSS-селекторами

```
.main-column-figure:nth-child(odd) {
    /* Стили для чётных элементов */
}
.main-column-figure:nth-child(even) {
    /* Стили для нечётных элементов */
}
```

PS: в приведённом в вопросе коде на каждой итерации верстка разметка выводится 2 раза. следует оставить один вывод.

Comment: я сделал это по своюму                                                                                                 .main-column-figure.fl {
    background: url(/images/cont-img-shadow.png) 0 100% no-repeat;
    margin-right: 7px;
}
.main-column-figure.fr {
    background: url(/images/content-img-shadow2.png) 100% 100% no-repeat;
}

Answer (score -4):

Убрать дубляж можно запросом

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE somecondition GROUP BY `somebrandname`
```

Я думаю как-то так

```
<?php
if($id_post%2==0) $classname="class1";
 else $classname="class2";
?>
<div class="<?=$classname?>">Content</div>
```

Comment: Дублирование-то не из БД прилетает, а делается при выводе.

Comment: Если при выводе, то можно использовать in_array с проверкой, если такой пост в контрольном массиве есть, то не выводить